# Using F# Option Type in C#

Tags: c#, f#, option-type

I have the following type:

```ml
and ListInfo() =

let mutable count = 0

// This is a mutable option because we can't have an infinite data structure.
let mutable lInfo : Option<ListInfo> = None

let dInfo = new DictInfo()
let bInfo = new BaseInfo()

member this.BaseInfo = bInfo
member this.DictInfo = dInfo

member this.LInfo
    with get() = lInfo
    and set(value) = lInfo <- Some(value)

member this.Count
    with get() = count
    and set(value) = count <- value
```

where the recursive "list info" is an Option. Either there is one or there is none. I need to use this from C# but I get errors. This is a sample usage:

```
if (FSharpOption<Types.ListInfo>.get_IsSome(listInfo.LInfo))
{
    Types.ListInfo subListInfo = listInfo.LInfo.Value;
    HandleListInfo(subListInfo, n);
}
```

here listInfo is of the type ListInfo as above. I'm just trying to check if it contains a value and if so I want to use it. But all the accesses listInfo.LInfo gives the error "Property, indexer or event listInfo.LInfo is not supported by the language..."

Anyone that understands why?

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with the Option type... It looks like a property declared in F# is not recognized by C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `LInfo` property getter/setter work with different types (which isn't supported in C#).

Try this

```
member this.LInfo
    with get() = lInfo
    and set value = lInfo <- value
```

Or this

```
member this.LInfo
    with get() = match lInfo with Some x -> x | None -> Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    and set value = lInfo <- Some value
```

Comment: It's not just that it's not supported by C# - I don't think it's supposed to be supported in F# either...

Comment: @kvb: You're right: From section 8.13.1 of the spec: _If a property member has both a getter and a setter, and neither is an indexer, then the signatures of both getter and setter must imply the same property type._

Comment: Filed a bug report. Although, this would be a breaking change.

Comment: oh, that's pretty cool that I stumbled upon it :). Didn't know it was against the spec.