# F# properties vs. C# properties

Tags: c#, f#, properties

In developing an F# application, I have a type that comprises a property of type `Lazy<'T>`.

Apparently, one interesting side effect (pardon the pun) of the way that F# handles the syntactical sugar of properties (as opposed to the C# way) is that the getter and setter of a property may return/accept *different* types.  (At least, Visual Studio is not complaining as I write code that takes advantage of this observation.)

For example, it is advantageous for me to do this:

```ml
let lazyValue = lazy 0

member this.Value
    with get () =
        lazyValue.Value
    and set _lazyVal =
        lazyValue <- _lazyVal
```

... such that Value *returns* an `int`, but *accepts* only a `Lazy<int>`.

What I am wondering about are the theoretical, idiomatic, and practical objections to doing things this way.  Is this something at which an F# snob would turn up his nose?  Is there some functional programming rule of thumb that this (object-oriented implementation) clearly violates?  Is this an approach that has been demonstrated to cause problems in large-scale applications?  If so, why/how?

Comment: That this is allowed is a bug in the F# compiler -- the F# spec says it's illegal. Expect this to no longer work in future versions of F#. :-]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it is a bug that "Visual Studio is not complaining as [you] write code that takes advantage of this observation".  See [Using F# Option Type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8590698/385844)

A comment in the answer to the linked question notes:

> From section 8.13.1 of the spec: If a property member has both a getter and a setter, and neither is an indexer, then the signatures of both getter and setter must imply the same property type